# How to disable or delay "Time Machine hasn't backed up your computer in x days" message?

Tags: macos, time-machine

Mountain Lion and later OS X releases have a very useful feature where Time Machine can alternate between multiple backup destinations. I use this to back up to both a network share at home and an external drive I keep offsite. Because I only have physical access to the offsite drive occasionally, I don't back up to it often.

After 10 days, OS X gives me a message around the same time each day, such as:
[image: Time Machine hasn't backed up your computer in 120 days]

Time Machine is still backing up successfully to the network share every hour, so this message is unnecessary (and the second sentence is incorrect).

I like being able to see when the last backup was completed, so I'd prefer not to remove the disk from Time Machine's destination list entirely. Likewise, turning Time Machine off (as suggested [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/194720/how-can-i-disable-the-no-backup-in-x-days-from-timemachine)) isn't an option because I still need my backups to run on the other drives.

Is there any way to disable or delay this message? Ideally I would be able to set it to a longer period of time, so it could remind me to go do an offsite backup every month or so.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation. This message get's really irritating after a while :(

Comment: Even worse - it interrupts Keynote presentations!

Comment: 4 OS X releases and almost 4 years later, the warning now comes as a notification that stays onscreen until manually cleared, but otherwise the problem remains unsolved. It looks like Apple doesn't provide a way to do this without disabling Time Machine. Third-party utilities didn't pan out, but it might be possible to solve with a script.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps [TimeMachineScheduler](http://www.klieme.com/TimeMachineScheduler.html) or [TimeMachineEditor](http://timesoftware.free.fr/timemachineeditor/) can help.

Comment: Interesting idea. TimeMachineScheduler seemed to be unable to trigger a backup at all - not sure whether that's because it doesn't support multiple backup destinations or because the one I can use right now is a network share. I'm watching TimeMachineEditor now to see if it works.

Comment: TimeMachineEditor is triggering backups successfully, on the downside it only does so for the first disk unlike the default behaviour which rotates through all available disks.

Comment: Correction: It triggers a backup for the last drive I backed up to, and complains with a dialog box if the drive isn't available. No, that won't do... :/